# libgsf - Child by name returns only GsfInput

Tags: gnome

I'm using libgsf library to create a structed file with some nested childs.

for example: A(root) -> B( dir) -> C (dir)
A is the root, B is a child directory and of a and C is child directory of B.

later on, when I have only the root I want to add a child to C so I want to open the path up to C, but if I open C it returns it as GsfInputFile.

```
GsfInput* gsf_infile_child_by_name (GsfInfile *infile, char const *name);
```

In order to add child to C I need it to be GsfOutFile, but I can only get c as inputFile.

```
GsfOutput* gsf_outfile_new_child (GsfOutfile *outfile, char const *name, gboolean is_dir);
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks